# Handshake failure while trying to send mail using openssl

Tags: linux, terminal, openssl, smtp

I am trying to send mail from terminal using openssl by connecting to gmail's server using ssl on the port 465. Things are fine until i enter from address and authenticate. But when i enter RCPT TO, i get the following error.

```
RCPT TO: <abc@gmail.com>
RENEGOTIATING
139815845389984:error:1409E0E5:SSL routines:SSL3_WRITE_BYTES:ssl handshakefailure:s3_pkt.c:59
```

I can guess out that the problem might be due to missing security certificates. Can someone please help me solve the problem?

Answer (score 8):

I stumbled upon the same issue and finally found an answer [here](https://forums.zoho.com/topic/renegotiating-when-providing-the-rcpt-to). Quoting it in SO in case people won't find the original answer:

The "renegotiating" happens as you are typing RCPT TO with "R" in Caps. That is how s_client is behaving. You may try entering "rcpt to" instead of "RCPT TO".

I tried with "rcpt to" and it worked like charm.

Comment: Still valid as of 7/1/2022, at least with HostGator's SMTP/TLS. 'RCPT TO' fails, 'rcpt to' succeeds. Weird...

Answer (score 2):

When **`openssl s_client`** is executed without `-quiet` or `-ign_eof`:

**At beginning of a line:**

- **R** → renegotiate session
- **Q** → quit session

---

per [`s_client`](https://www.openssl.org/docs/man1.1.0/apps/s_client.html):

```
CONNECTED COMMANDS
    If a connection is established with an SSL server then any data
    received from the server is displayed and any key presses will be sent
    to the server. When used interactively (which means neither -quiet nor
    -ign_eof have been given), the session will be renegotiated if the line
    begins with an R, and if the line begins with a Q or if end of file is
    reached, the connection will be closed down.
```